# Set graphics shared memory size

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

The background is: Microsoft Surface device with Intel HD graphics. BIOS here doesn't have any settings for integrated graphics shared memory and the default value is 50%, which is 8GB of my RAM.

The problem, as it looks to me, grows from a regular garbage collection  (GC) trigger condition, which is I guess 50% or maybe 80% graphics memory used. So on discrete GeForce with 2GB memory they perfectly fit in 1GB, but on integrated Intel only Firefox easily eats up a 4GB of RAM as graphics shared memory, which is unacceptable.

So the qustion is how to limit the graphics shared memory without corresponding setting in BIOS?

Comment: "Shared" does not mean "in use". It *can* use up to 4GB if you are running demanding graphics applications, but normally it will only use a small amount. It will only use as much as it needs. Letting your system just work is for the best.

Comment: "Shared" means "can be used" and many apps, like Firefox or Photoshop are using it freely. The problem, as it looks to me, grows from a regular garbage collection  (GC) trigger condition, which is I guess 50% or maybe 80% graphics memory used. So on discrete GeForce with 2GB memory they perfectly fit in 1GB, but on integrated Intel only Firefox easily eats up a 4GB of RAM as graphics shared memory, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Use your discrete card instead and you won't have that problem? How did you check that consumption? What issues is it causing?

Comment: Please guys, if you don't have a direct answer, do not suggest me change video card, PC, app, life...